# Changing the volume of a simple soundchannel

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio, actionscript, air

I would like to change the volume of a soundchannel, instead of turning it off/ starting it from the beginning.

Here is a bit of my code dealing with the soundchannel, `musicIcon` toggles the sound.

```
    function musicToggle(e:TouchEvent){
    if(musicIcon.alpha != 1){
        Chn_musicLoop = musicLoop.play(0,int.MAX_VALUE);
//Instead of restarting the music, I would like to set the volume to it's max (1)
        musicIcon.alpha *= 2;
    }
    else{
        musicIcon.alpha *= .5;
        Chn_musicLoop.stop();
//Instead of stopping the music, I would like to set the volume to 0.
    }}
```

What code would I need to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for `SoundTransform` class.

Basically:

```
var st:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform(0.5, 0);

Chn_musicLoop.soundTransform = st;
```

The `SoundTransform` parameter of `0.5` would put your "volume" at halfway. The parameter is a range from 0 to 1.

Here's a reference in AS3 from adobe:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d1f.html

Comment: And if I wanted to set it to 0 half the time and 1 the other half?

Comment: The same rules apply, you set the `SoundTransform` variable to a new `SoundTransform`, adjust the first parameter, then apply it to your `SoundChannel` (`Chn_musicLoop`) as shown in the answer.